# Table shows only 50 entries

Tags: angular, angular5

My table has pagination to display 13 items per page.

Lets assume that I am creating new "user" and I have specific modal to create user where I can fill all data. Once user is created, the most basic info about the user shows up in the table Name, address, email, and phone.

Now if I create 50 users they are displayed correctly in my table and my pagination works perfectly. If I create more than 50 users. My 51th and any user going forward from number 50 does not appear in table at all!

I checked my database, and entry is there successfully created in POSTGRES TABLE.. for 51th,52th bla bla but there is no data in the HTML TABLE

Could you please check where the mistake is in the code. ( I do not think pagination is the issue, since when I increase it to even 100 items per page it does not do anything)

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;margin-left:15px;">
   <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="table-col">
            <div class="card table">
               <div class="row header">
                  <div class="col col-md-6">Name</div>
                  <div class="col col-md-2">Email</div>
                  <div class="col col-md-2">Address</div>
                  <div class="col col-md-2">Phone</div>
               </div>
               <div *ngFor="let group of users">
                  <div *ngIf="group.name == 'all'">
                     <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let user of group.array |  search: term | orderBy: order | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 13, currentPage:page1, id: '1'}"
                     [routerLink]="['/user/edit', user.id]">
                     <div class="col col-md-6">{{user.fullname}}</div>
                     <div class="col col-md-2">{{user.email}}</div>
                     <div class="col col-md-2">{{user.address}}</div>
                     <div *ngIf="user.phone != null" class="col col-md-2">{{user.phone}}
                     </div>
                     <div *ngIf="user.phone == null" class="col col-md-2"><span class="badge badge-danger">-- N/A -- </span></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div *ngIf="group.name != 'all'">
                  <div class="row content-row">
                     <div class="col col-md-12 group-name" (click)="toggleGroup(group.name)">{{group.name + ':'}}</div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="showGroup == group.name">
                     <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let user of group.array | search: term |   paginate: {itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage:page2, id: '2'}"
                     [routerLink]="['/user/edit', user.id]">
                     <div class="col col-md-6" style="padding-left:23px;">{{user.fullname}}</div>
                     <div class="col col-md-2">{{user.email}}</div>
                     <div class="col col-md-2">{{user.address}}/div>
                     <div class="col col-md-2">{{user.phone}}
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div *ngIf="!(users[0].array.length > 0)" class="row noResults">
            <label>No results..</label>
         </div>
         <div *ngIf="users[0].name == 'all'" class="paggination-row">
            <div class="paggination">
               <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page1 = $event" id="1" maxSize="5" directionLinks="true" autoHide="true" previousLabel="Previous"
                  nextLabel="Next">
               </pagination-controls>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div *ngIf="user[0].name != 'all' && showGroup != ''" class="paggination-row">
            <div class="paggination">
               <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page2 = $event" id="2" maxSize="5" directionLinks="true" autoHide="true" previousLabel="Previous"
                  nextLabel="Next">
               </pagination-controls>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In component ts:

```
     order = 'name';
        users: any = [{
            name: 'all',
            array: []
        }];
showGroup = '';


    loadUsers() {
        this.userService.getAll().subscribe(res => {
            this.users[0].array = res.data;
        }, err => {
            this.toast.error('Users: ' + JSON.parse(err._body).message, 'FAILED')
        })
    }
  toggleGroup(group) {
        if(this.showGroup == group) {
            this.showGroup = '';
        } else {
            this.showGroup = group;
        }
    }

 this.userService.currentData.subscribe(res => {
            if (res == 'default') { //subscribe to shared data
                this.loadUsers();
            } else {
                this.users= res;
            }
        })
```

This is the userService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AppSettings } from '../../../../../../app.settings';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

//service made to comunicate with backend
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>("default")
    currentData = this.dataSource.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ) { }

    updateData(data) {
        this.dataSource.next(data);
    }

    getAll() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/user', { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    getOne(id) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/user?id=' + id, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    createNew(user) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.post(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/user', user, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    delete(id) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.delete(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/user?id=' + id, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    edit(id, user) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.patch(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/user?id=' + id, user, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

I have pasted only parts of code in component.ts that are relevant in this case, everything else are functions that have nothing to do with this.

I have read this code over 50 times now I have no idea what causes table not to present more than 50 entries.

If you can have a look and let me know what could be the issue, I would be appreciate it very much!

Comment: do you get all entries (50+) from your userService? If not show us the code where you fetch your data

Comment: As @PascalRuscher said. what is the result of loadUsers(): `console.log(this.users[0])`

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I have updated my first post with complete userservice if this is what you have looked for.

Comment: @Z.Bagley this is the result of loadusers Object
array
:
(50) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
name
:
"all"
__proto__
:
Object    IT says that array length is 50? how come and where can I change this

Comment: So there are only 50 items coming from your backend, the issue lies in your backend code it seems

Comment: Yeah I think your backend only gives you 50 entries as @user184994 said

Comment: @Horcrux It's like a LIMIT value set to 50 by default. Wherever you configure your backend (it can be either the server or the actual db with this limit) you'll have to update that limit value.

Comment: What do you use as backend (software)? If it's not custom maybe we can help some more

Comment: I have found this option on backend and changed the value and it works. Thanks for all help you wonderful people! :) write an answer like in the comment so i can mark it as valid answer :)